How to make fake domain in local when develop web application?
in local web development, the app is running at http://localhost:3000
I want to use a domain instead of localhost and set this in /etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1    localhost    mydomain.com

But when I access mydomain.com:3000, it got DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error.
How to do then?
Is there a way don't use mydomain.com:3000 but mydomain.com only to do local development?
